# How can I speed up this Monte Carlo integration for the Stieltjes constant $\gamma_n$?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, parallelization, random

## Pre-requisite Definition

[Stieltjes constants ($\gamma_n$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) are the constants that occur in the Laurent series expansion of the Riemann zeta function.
$${\displaystyle \zeta (s)={\frac {1}{s-1}}+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{n!}}\gamma _{n}(s-1)^{n}.}$$

They have a finite integral representation as follows,
$${\displaystyle \gamma _{n}={\frac {(-1)^{n}n!}{2\pi }}\int _{0}^{2\pi }e^{-nix}\zeta \left(e^{ix}+1\right)dx.}$$

## Code

I have writen the following simple Monte Carlo algorithm for computing $\gamma_n$.

***Note:** I'm aware of MonteCarlo method in `NIntegrate`. The purpose of this code is more to understand/motivate the algorithm involved in crude MC Integration and I want to define it myself.*

```
sint[n_, x_] := Exp[-n I x] Zeta[Exp[I x] + 1]
lowerlim = 0; upperlim = 2 Pi;
ParallelRepeatedStieltjesIntegral[n_, points_, repeat_] := 
((-1)^n n!)/(2 Pi) ParallelTable[(upperlim - lowerlim)/points Total[sint[n, RandomReal[{lowerlim, upperlim}, {points}]]], {repeat}]
```

My question is as follows, **How can I speed up this code?**

### Extra Info

Time taken to execute this code on my PC

- `ParallelRepeatedStieltjesIntegral[1, 10^3, 10^5]` took 40 minutes!
- `ParallelRepeatedStieltjesIntegral[2, 10^3, 10^5]` took 32 minutes!

Also at the end of all this the values are quite poor (2 digit accuracy). I would prefer to run this code with larger *points* values.

I also want to repeat it, for the purpose of displaying the histogram (as this nicely demonstrates the law of large numbers).

**PS:** A not very relevant side question, how do you generate quasirandom numbers in Mathematica, instead of pseudorandom. (To demonstrate quasi-Monte Carlo integration in similar code as above.)

Comment: I would not use Monte-Carlo for this integral but rather FFT.

Comment: Hi Henrik, my goal really is just a showcase of MC integration nothing else. Mathematica even has a built in function as StieltjesGamma[n]. FFT is without a doubt practically better, but that's not the reason I'm doing it.

Comment: I would not use `Parallel*` functions but rather use packed arrays and vectorized operations (which are automatically and very efficiently parallelized).  Search for “[performance-tuning] packed” and sort by votes. The top two hits make good introductory reading. (Sorry on an iOS device w/o Mathematica at present and cannot show you. Several others on site know how, though.)

Comment: I'm really quite confused how to use packed arrays here, Micheal. It's the first time I'm hearing about it.

Comment: "Monte Carlo is an extremely bad method; it should only be used when all alternative methods are worse." - Alan Sokal. With that said, 1D integrals are usually a poor choice for demonstrating (quasi-)Monte Carlo; you might prefer using a 2D example instead, especially one where the region of integration is not necessarily amenable to a conversion to an iterated integral.

Comment: With that said, the built-in [`"MKL"` generator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#57850632) implements the Sobol' and Niederreiter sequences, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slowest part of the code is clearly `Zeta`. You have to compute it only on a small parameter range and you also do not much very high accuracy (as Monte Carlo won't deliver much accuracy, too). So you can just sample `Zeta` over a fixed grid and use an interpolation function instead. Mathematica's interpolation functions are notoriously slow, so I implement my own compiled function here; it only uses piecewise-linear interpolation but nevertheless delivers 6 digits of precision.

```
sub = 2000;
tlist = Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, sub];
zeta = Zeta[1. + Exp[I tlist]];
cF = With[{zeta = zeta, tlist = tlist, L = sub/(2. Pi)},
   Compile[{{t, _Real}},
    Block[{i, \[Lambda]},
     i = Floor[Mod[t, 2. Pi]  L] + 1;
     \[Lambda] = (t - tlist[[i]]) L;
     (1. - \[Lambda]) zeta[[i]] + \[Lambda] zeta[[i + 1]]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

I also made a couple of small modifictions in the remaining code:

```
sint[n_, x_] := Exp[-n I x] cF[x]
lowerlim = 0.; 
upperlim = 2. Pi;
ParallelRepeatedStieltjesIntegral[n_, points_, 
  repeat_] := (((-1)^n n!)/(2. Pi) (upperlim - lowerlim))  ParallelTable[
   Mean[sint[n, RandomReal[{lowerlim, upperlim}, {points}]]], {repeat},
   Method -> "CoarsestGrained"
   ]
```

Now this runs within a couple of seconds on my machine:

```
ParallelRepeatedStieltjesIntegral[2, 10^3, 10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.83621

If you want to run the computations for various values of `n` anyways, you can save some time i) by using the same random points `x` for all `n` inequestion so that `cF[x]` has to be computed only once and ii) by computing only `Exp[- I x]` once and by computing `Exp[-I n x]` by multiplication. For example, the following does the computations for the first 100 coefficients at once, while it requires only about twelve times longer than for doing it for a single coefficient:

```
points = 10^3;
repeat = 10^5;
n1 = 1;
n2 = 100;

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  result = ParallelTable[
     Block[{x, Fx, z, factor, pow},
      x = RandomReal[{lowerlim, upperlim}, {points}];
      Fx = cF[x];
      z = Exp[(-I) x];
      factor = (upperlim - lowerlim)/(2. Pi)/points;
      pow = ConstantArray[1., Length[z]];
      Table[
       pow *= z;
       ((-1)^n n! factor) (pow.Fx)
       , {n, n1, n2}]
      ]
     , {repeat},
     Method -> "CoarsestGrained"
     ];
  ]
```

> 34.5558

For comparison, computing all the `Exp[-I n x]` directly lead to a runtime of `109.031` s.

No guarantees for correctness, though.

Comment: Marvelous, I have a long way to go in learning Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you! "Marvelous, I have a long way to go in learning Mathematica." -- But you actually did everything right! You used `sint` in the `Listable` way so that vectorization was enabled (in principle), you created packed arrays of random numbers with `RandomReal` and used parallelization only at the outer level. The only issue was that `Zeta` was implemented for correctness on (almost) the whole complex plane. Since you need only a simple, compact subregion of the complex plain and only quite low precision, this is a thing that we can exploit here.